# Duplicate icons in apps list

Tags: java, android

I get list of apps, but i get in list dublicate icons like this:

[image]

At first time everything was fine, after the few time begin the duplication icons :(

Code:

```
@Override
protected ArrayList<Order> doInBackground(String... params) {

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    appsList = new ArrayList<Order>();          
    Drawable img = null;
    Intent intent;

    try {
        List<PackageInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < packages.size(); i++) {
            PackageInfo pi = packages.get(i);
            ApplicationInfo ai = pi.applicationInfo;

            intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pi.packageName);
            if(intent != null) {
                img = ai.loadIcon(pm);
            }                   

            Order o = new Order();
            o.setTextName(ai.loadLabel(pm).toString());
            o.setTextPackageName(pi.packageName);
            o.setTextVersion(pi.versionName);
            o.setTextVersionCode(pi.versionCode);
            o.setImage(img);
            appsList.add(o);

        };
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return appsList;
}
```

Custom adapter:

```
public class myAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Order> {

private LayoutInflater lInflater;
private ArrayList<Order> data;
private Order o;
Context ctx;
Drawable noImage;

public myAdapter(Context c, int appsList, ArrayList<Order> data) {
    super(c, appsList, data);
    lInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    this.data = data;
    ctx = c;
    noImage = c.getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textName);
        holder.textPackageName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textPackageName);
        holder.textVersion = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textVersion);
        holder.textVersionCode = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textVersionCode);
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageLogo);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    o = data.get(position);
    holder.image.setTag(o);

    if (o.getImage() == null) {
        holder.image.setImageDrawable(noImage);
    } else {
        holder.image.setImageDrawable(o.getImage());
    }
    holder.textName.setText(o.getTextName());
    holder.textName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    holder.textPackageName.setText(o.getTextPackageName());
    holder.textPackageName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    holder.textVersion.setText("v." + o.gettTextVersion() + "  ");
    holder.textVersion.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2E64FE"));
    holder.textVersionCode
            .setText("v.c." + Integer.toString(o.getTextVersionCode()));
    holder.textVersionCode.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#01DFD7"));

    holder.textName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        int texTimetPos = position;
        int textNamePos = position;
        int linkPos = position;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), Details.class);
            // i.putExtra("time",
            // data.get(texTimetPos).getTextTime().toString());
            // i.putExtra("name",
            // data.get(textNamePos).getTextName().toString());
            // i.putExtra("url",
            // data.get(linkPos).getDetailsUrl().toString());
            // ctx.startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView textName, textPackageName, textVersion, textVersionCode;
    ImageView image;
}
```

How i can fix it?

Comment: The code looks good to me! there must be issue with the custom adapter you are using to display listview.Post the custom adapter code.

Comment: are you clearing your arraylist?

Comment: Clear by the appsList.clear(); and `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`, does not work

Comment: Problem solved. This is incorrect for me ` if(intent != null) {
                img = ai.loadIcon(pm);
            }` I put only `img = ai.loadIcon(pm);` and it's work!